# cannot find "for loop" keyword in robot framework

Tags: keyword, robotframework

I am currently connecting SQL server to robot framework, so i can read my data table name in robot. and I want to use for loop to check table name, somehow, ":FOR" loop keyword cannot found, but I have installed libraries such as operating-system, collections, string, built-in, diff-library and so on. anyone can help me why i cannot use for loop? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean ":FOR loop keyword cannot be found". It's built in -- if you can run robot, that keyword will exist. Can you show an example of how you are trying to use it, and the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks, it is working now. go to text edit, delete the for and retype it again, will be able to run

Answer (score 3):

The robot framework users guide has a [whole section on how to use the for loop](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops). From that section:

> The syntax starts with :FOR, where colon is required to separate the
>   syntax from normal keywords. The next cell contains the loop variable,
>   the subsequent cell must have IN, and the final cells contain values
>   over which to iterate. These values can contain variables, including
>   list variables.

Here's an example from the user's guide, reformatted to use pipes (for clarity):

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example 1
| | :FOR | ${animal} | IN | cat | dog
| | | log | ${animal}
| | | log | 2nd keyword
| | Log | Outside loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not escaping indented cells; as the `Tip` in the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops) says. Try writing loops like this:

```
:FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${start}    ${stop}
\    log to console    index: ${index}
\    Call a Keyword
```